# How can I get the dimensions of Material TimePicker/DatePicker?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

Google's [Material.io](http://material.io) website has the specs for many components, except for TimePicker/DatePicker ([docs for Dialogs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs)). I need to create a custom dialog with a header like these components, so I need to know the header height and text sizes.

How can I find these information?

[image: DatePicker]

Comment: Refer [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_header_material.xml). It will help you

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: I added as answer. In future help to anyone. So kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per @Juliano Nunes Silva Oliveira Comment. Following link is useful.

You can get dimension from source code of [DatePicker](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_header_material.xml)